# Merging two exported modules

Tags: typescript

I'm unsure about how to go about this, perhaps I'm doing it wrong.  I need to spread the SAME module ('A') across *different* files (TypeScript's JS output shows they will "merge" as they execute). Examples:

```
---File1.ts---
export module A { export class X { } }

---File2.ts---
export module A { export class Y extends X { } }
```

This of course wraps the modules in a "define()" function, but A.X in file2 shows an error in Visual Studio that it doesn't exist (and the intellisense doesn't show it).  Is it possible to do this as shown above? I'm aware I have to use "import varname = require(...);", but that doesn't seem to help any.

BTW: I'm aware of using references, and it doesn't help.

See here for an example: http://goo.gl/zlVKRv  - The JS code clearly shows support for loading multiple modules of the same name for combination, so I'm not sure why the compiler and intellisense won't work.  Seems like a bug to me.

Just to reiterate: The main issue is that I need the compiler and intellisense to "see" the dependent modules as one from file2.

What I was hoping to do was something like this:

```
import mod = require("test1");
import A = mod.A;

export module A {
    export class Y extends X {
    }
}
```

**Update 1:** Submitted this related request to have this process above working, or at least something similar:
https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1846

**Update 2:** Seems this ability is on the team's radar! 8)  A real answer should come in due time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible. You'll need to reference `X` by its fully-qualified name, i.e.:

```
---File1.ts---
export module A { export class X { } }

---File2.ts---
import f1 = require('./File1');
export module A { export class Y extends f1.A.X { } }
```

Comment: BTW: I never said I wanted to compile into one module; read again.

Comment: "I need to spread the SAME module across different files". What's intended by that statement?

Comment: Same *internal* module. I didn't realize you intended those to merge. Updating answer...

Comment: I disagree.  TS creates a "define()" function so that dependencies will load AND merge BEFORE the dependant module loads.

Comment: BTW: I can get this to work just fine, that's not the main issue.  The issue is that I need the compiler and intellisense to "see" the dependent modules.

Comment: The compiler will not treat File1.A and File2.A as being the same; I can't think of a workaround.

Comment: Perhaps a misunderstanding, but I don't want them to be the same.  I just want the compiler to allow me to type my example code above without complaining.

Comment: Actually, your answer is correct, but what I was hoping for was the ability to merge module A from one file with module A from another *internally* - and it is possible on the JS level, just not sure how to do it in TS. Something like:
    import mod = require("test1");
    import A = mod.A;

Comment: So there's no way at all, when editing file2, for intellisense to see "A.X" from file1 without resorting to typing a proxy name?  I wanted A.X to merge in when loaded and tried something like "import A = f1.A;" before "export module A {}", which seems to work AND compile just fine, but intellisense doesn't show "X" in file2 when typing "A.".

Comment: The TS team have confirmed that this isn't possible YET, but it's coming. :)

Comment: That RyanCavanaugh guy on the CodePlex site knows what he's talking about, eh? ;)

Comment: Just looked at your profile, LOL.  Didn't know. :) Well, the reason I asked is that I heard somewhere there's a way to "extend" the TS compiler within the project code, but I can't find the info now.  Thanks for your help Ryan. I'm not well acquainted with the names of people working behind the scenes on projects I'm working with these days.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using VisualStudio, try drag/dropping File1.ts onto the File2.ts editor and that should help the IDE understand A.X.

Comment: I'm aware of using references, and it doesn't help.

Comment: You should not use reference tags between external modules.

Comment: I wouldn't have answered my question this way if he would have posted the playground reference to begin with.